# Issue with pushing additional values in a embeds_many mongoid relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have been breaking my head around this for a long time now. Not sure if my approach is correct or if its not possible using mongoid. SO without further adieu, here is the problem:

I have the following 2 models:

```
def user
  embeds_many :needs, :class_name => "Property"
  embeds_many :skills, :class_name => "Property"
end

def property

end
```

Both these models of course have other code but I have skipped that for brevity.
With this structure I am able to access/add "Property" data as embedded "needs" & "skills" on my user model. Something like this works flawlessly

```
User.first.update_attributes(skills: [Property.first])
```

The problem is something like this doesn't work.

```
User.first.skills.push(Property.first)
User.first.skills << Property.first
```

There is no error. Both the above statements return true on console. But the values don't persist to the DB.

I basically want a Property model which can be maintained/created independent of the User model, thats why the "embedded_in" on Property is missing in my code.

The question is, am I doing it right? Or there is their a different way that I should go about the design of these models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cage is right. You will need to put the embedded_in on the Property model if you want the persistence to work properly. If you want to manage the lifecycle of Property outside the User model, you will have to use 'has_many'.

Please add more details as to what exactly is the purpose of doing what you are doing. I am going to make some assumptions-

- Needs and skills are a global list of values, that should be maintained separately
- User can have a subset of skills and needs
- You want to store the needs and skills as 'plain string' and not references so you can query them without referencing the needs and skills collection. This reduces one query

If the above is correct, then you can use custom keys to store the needs and skills-

```
class Property
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :text, :type => String
  field :_id, type: String, default ->{ text }
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :needs, :class_name => "Property"
  has_many :skills, :class_name => "Property"
end
```

Now you can do something like-

```
User.first.need_ids
```

This will give the text of the need and you can avoid another query.
**Note**- that this is potentially very risky if your 'Property' objects are mutable.

Answer (score 0):

For solution try doing this

```
u = User.first
u.skills.push(Property.first)
u.skills << Property.first
```

it will work fine.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either. I had tried that as well earlier.

Comment: If you want to create\maintain property independent then reference relation in between user property like has_many rather than embedded...For embeds_many to work you have to put embedded_in inside property class and you cannot create Property independently.